# class_eval producing an empty string when value present

Tags: ruby

This works fine:

```
"1234567890".scan(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d*)/).flatten.join('-')
 => "123-456-7890"
```

Now I put it in a method evaluated with class_eval:

```
> class Apple
> end
> Apple.class_eval <<-EOS
> def orange
> "1234567890".scan(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d*)/).flatten.join('-')
> end
> EOS
 => :orange 
> a = Apple.new
 => #<Apple:0x007f8094276638> 
> a.orange
 => ""
```

Why does it give me an empty string rather than the expected value?

Comment: I would use block instead of string... `Apple.class_eval { def orange; "1234567890".scan(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d*)/).flatten.join('-'); end }`

Comment: It looks like you're trying to turn a string of digits into a phone number. Internationally it's possible to find phone numbers using more or less digits or that are represented differently. See "[National conventions for writing telephone numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers)" for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Apple.class_eval <<-EOS
  def orange
    return "1234567890".scan(%r{(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d*)}).flatten.join('-')
  end
EOS
```

double-backslashes. Don't ask me why.

Comment: Can I ask you why?

Comment: It takes doubled-backslashes because you're using a HERE-TO doc, which is basically a string. Strings require double-backslashes to generate a backslash character.

Comment: You can also use `<<-'EOS'` and single backslashes. The single quotes makes the heredoc behave like a single-quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ways to fix your code.

```
class Apple
end
str =<<-EOF
  def orange
    '1234567890'.scan(/(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d*)/).flatten.join('-')
  end
EOF
  #=> "  def orange\n    '1234567890'.scan(/(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d*)/).flatten.join('-')\n  end\n"
puts str
Apple.class_eval str

Apple.new.orange
  # => "123-456-7890"
```

The following is `put`ted, which shows the effect of using single quotes and escaping backslashes to convert them to characters:

```
def orange
  '1234567890'.scan(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d*)/).flatten.join('-')
end
```

Look at the return value of `str`. Firstly, I used single quotes around `1234567890`. If double-quotes are used they are escaped, so the substring is no longer defined.

The other way is to use a block, which, as you can see, has some advantages here.

```
class Apple
end
Apple.class_eval do 
  def orange
    "1234567890".scan(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d*)/).flatten.join('-')
  end
end

Apple.new.orange
  # => "123-456-7890"
```